# VBA - handling many nested loops - different collections - the same logic inside loop

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I have a web scraping VBA macro with Internet Explorer, for a shop which has many item categories. In each category there are another categories, products or both categories and products.

Upon opening every page I first check if there are any products, if yes - list them and then open all categories listed on this page and do the same for all subcategories.

What bothers me is that logic for all loop nest levels is the same, but variables are different. Is there any way to handle it so that all logic would go to one big sub which I could use on all loop levels?

```
Dim htmlele1 as IHTMLElement, htmlele2 as IHTMLElement, htmlele3 as IHTMLElement
For Each htmlele1 In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("A")
   'check for products and list them if any
   'check for categories, if there are any, open next IE instance (let's call this instance ie2,ie3 etc.)

   For Each htmlele2 In ie2.document.getElementsByTagName("A")
      'check for products and list them if any
      'check for categories, if there are any, open next IE instance (let's call this instance ie2,ie3 etc.)

      For Each htmlele3 In ie3.document.getElementsByTagName("A")
         'check for products and list them if any
         'check for categories, if there are any, open next IE instance (let's call this instance ie2,ie3 etc.)

      next htmlele3       
   next htmlele2
next htmlele1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like recursion to me.  Here is the pattern that I would follow:

```
Sub Main()
    Const BASEURL = "www.example.com"
    Dim dProducts As Object
    Set dProducts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    FillProductsList BASEURL, dProducts

End Sub

Sub FillProductsList(URL As String, ByRef dProducts As Object)
    Dim ele As HTMLAnchorElement
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Set doc = getDocument(URL)

    If Not doc Is Nothing Then

        For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("A")

            If isCategory(ele) Then

                FillProductsList ele.href, dProducts

            ElseIf isProduct(ele) Then

                dProducts.Add getProduct(ele)

            End If

        Next

    End If


End Sub

Function isCategory(ele As HTMLAnchorElement) As Boolean

End Function

Function isProduct(ele As HTMLAnchorElement) As Boolean

End Function

Function getProduct(ele As HTMLAnchorElement) As String

End Function

Function getDocument(URL As String) As HTMLDocument

End Function
```